# An explorer pane in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I'd like to have a Windows Explorer-style left pane in Notepad++.  Is there an add-on or plugin that accomplishes this?

Comment: It's *right there* in https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/

Comment: @Mehrdad There's a plugin manager in the program.  I prefer to use that b/c installing them manually is more of a chore and presents a greater security risk.  Thanks, though.  +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this guide:

Click Plugins on the menu > plugin manager > show plugin manager > select Explorer > click install > restart Notepad++ > Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (or select Plugins from the menu > explorer > Explorer ...)

That's it.

Comment: Quo min tang you.

Comment: this is not working with latest version of np++, i found another and even better SherloXplorer